# Как передать параметр в событие button?

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме есть кнопка при нажатии на нее вызывается событие `btn_Click`, в которой есть функция `someFunc` с параметром `param`, как можно передать этот параметр ?

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   someFunc(param);
}
```

Comment: Сделать `param` полем формы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
btn.Tag = param;

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   someFunc(((Control)sender).Tag);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Например можно так:

```
string param = "fdgdfgd"; //допустим ваш параметр string

// public string Param { get; set; } или так

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   someFunc(param);
}
```